# NSOperationQueue leak?

Tags: ios, multithreading, nsoperation

I am trying to perform a method in a background thread using a NSOperationQueue like so:

```
NSOperationQueue *queue = [NSOperationQueue new];
    NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                            selector:@selector(method)
                                                                              object:nil];

    [queue addOperation:operation];
    [queue release];
    [operation release];
```

The problem is that, analyzer says that there is a leak that is stored into queue.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling [MyClass new] is the same as calling [[MyClass alloc] init], it return object with retainCount = 1.
So, it should be released after.

Comment: How is the code above, the analyzer warning went away but I just want to make sure I am doing the right thing!

Answer (score 1):

Are you releasing `operation` object? Try to add `autorelease` keyword

```
    NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                                selector:@selector(method)
                                                                                  object:nil] autorelease];
```

Comment: I am already releasing operation, its the 4th line in the code I posted. Am I leaking queue?

Answer (score 1):

Just wondering, what are you doing inside your method "method"? Are you using `NSAutoreleasePool`? By the way, use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557537/how-to-properly-use-autoreleasepool-for-an-nsoperationqueue) answer to help you out.